# Struct not being populated

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, arraylist, struct

I have a struct called `Item` and wish to populate its variables.

```
struct Item {
    var title: String
    var others: [String]
}
```

`Programs` is an array of all the `Item`’s created.

```
var Programs = [Item]()
```

I created a struct `Item` by the following:

```
var entered = Item(title: hello1, others: ["hello2"])
```

The problem is that when I go to print the list of `Items`, the programs array is empty

```
print(Programs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append it

```
print("Before :",programs)
let entered = Item(title: hello1, others: ["hello2"])
programs.append(entered) 
print("After:",programs)
```