# Populating an UITableview from a struct

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, struct

I have two viewControllers one called programlist that displays the list of tiles and populates a a suitable view.

the second viewController inputs the data. Issues implementing the callback due to an error in the `prepareForsegue` function. Getting the error "Instance member 'callback' cannot be used on type 'addWorkout'"

viewController 1 aka Programlist:

```
import UIKit

struct Item: Codable {
var title: String
var others: [String]
}

class ProgramList: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var Programs = [Item]()

@IBOutlet weak var programTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    load()
}

//saving current state of programs array
func save() {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(Programs) else { return }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
}

//loading saved program array
func load() {
    guard let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes")  else { return }
    do {
        Programs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: loadedData)
        programTableView.reloadData()
    } catch { print(error) }
}






func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Programs.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
              cell.programTitle.text = Programs[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
}

//Removing Item by swipping left & saving this newly established array
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        Programs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        programTableView.reloadData()
        save()
    }


    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toAddPage"{
            workoutController.callback = { [weak self] string in
                let entered = Item(title: string, others: ["hi"])
                self?.programs.append(entered)
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self?.programs.count - 1, section: 0)
                self?.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self?.save()
         }
       }
    }    
  }
}

  }
```

viewController 2 aka addWorkout:

```
 import UIKit

 class addWorkout: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var workoutTitle: UITextField!

var callback : ((String) -> Void)?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func saveWorkoutTitle(_ sender: Any) {

    if !workoutTitle.text!.isEmpty {
        callback?(workoutTitle.text!)
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code: the full `cellForRowAt`, any UITableCell overrides, the datasource methods......

Comment: Show us the table view data source method please.

Comment: Share your remaining code.

Comment: Please use proper way to ask question and try to learn your own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383482/struct-not-being-populated

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: You save `Programs` as an array of `Item` – which actually should throw an error – and then you load the data as array of `String`. This cannot work. And **never** declare a data source array outside of the class. Don't do that.

Comment: yes that section of code does not work. that is why i did not post the whole code originally. I am first trying to figure out how to populate the index path.rows with the titles first. I am just using print statements in testing to confirm or not if I have correctly generated the array of item titles.

Comment: The code to populate the table view is correct. However you have to reload the table view after appending an item. And once again, **do not** create the data source array outside of the class. Pass the string from `addWorkout` back to `ProgramList` and manage the array there.

Comment: if the data source array is not outside the class then I cannot populate it from the view controller that  i am inputing the data from though.

Comment: You can, you have to implement a callback or protocol/delegate to share the data between the controllers. Your way is strongly discouraged.

Comment: I don't understand why Programs as an array of items would throw an error? Right either way to fix this I need to try and sort out my load function and then i need to move my struct inside the class and figure out a way to write to my structure?

Answer (score 3):

The main mistake is you are trying to save an array of **`Item`** – which is not supported anyway – to `UserDefaults` and read an array of **`String`**. That's a clear type mismatch.

To be able to save an array of a custom struct to `UserDefaults` adopt `Codable` to save the struct as JSON.

```
struct Item : Codable {
    var title: String
    var others: [String]
}
```

Further it's a very bad practice to declare a data source array outside of any class.

This is the `ProgramList` class with adjusted `load` and `save` methods and the data source array inside the class. The method `viewDidAppear` is not needed.

```
class ProgramList: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var programTableView: UITableView!

    var programs = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        load()
    }

    //saving current state of programs array
    func save() {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(programs) else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
    }

    //loading saved program array
    func load() {
        guard let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes")  else { return }
        do {
            programs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: loadedData)
            programTableView.reloadData()
        } catch { print(error) }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return programs.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.programTitle.text = programs[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }

    //Removing Item by swipping left & saving this newly established array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            programs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            programTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            save()
        }
    }
}
```

To share data between controllers use a closure as callback and pass the string

```
class AddWorkout: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTitle: UITextField!

    var callback : ((String) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func saveWorkoutTitle(_ sender: Any) {
        if !workoutTitle.text!.isEmpty {
            callback?(workoutTitle.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

Back in `ProgramList` controller assign a closure to the `callback` property in `prepareForSegue` (or right before presenting the controller)

```
 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toAddPage" {
        let workoutController = segue.destination as! AddWorkout
        workoutController.callback = { string in
            let entered = Item(title: string, others: ["hi"])
            self.programs.append(entered)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.programs.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, just on the last section I have `workoutController.callback` changed to `addWorkout.callback` as this is the name of the swift file that I have added the details of the workout. However i get the error saying nstance member 'callback' cannot be used on type 'addWorkout'.                                                                I have this in a `prepareForSegue` function.

Comment: Please edit your question and add `prepareForSegue`. And once again name classes with starting capital letter according to the naming convention. This can avoid those errors because you see instantly what's type and what's instance.

Comment: Question edited and `prepareForSegue` has been added. Sorry for the naming convention. I will amend this in actual code.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. And don't edit the question and add parts of the solution. This will confuse other readers.